# Empty QuerySet for Django Multi-Table Inheritance Subclass

Tags: django, multi-table-inheritance

I have the following models:

```
APP 1:

class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    # custom fields etc
    # NOT ABSTRACT


APP 2:

class SecondaryUser(User):
    # other custom fields
```

When I do `SecondaryUser.objects.create(...)` I get an instance as expected:

```
In: SecondaryUser.objects.create(first_name='test', last_name='test', email='test@etest.com')
Out: <SecondaryUser>
```

This has an id and populated fields as expected. I can also query the base class and use the django-generated 1-1 field for the inheritance to access the subclass's fields:

`User.objects.get(email='test@etest.com').secondaryuser.<some_field>`

However when I do `SecondaryUser.objects.all()` it returns an empty queryset. And the model admin for the `SecondaryUser` shows an empty list view (even when I create a new instance of `SecondaryUser` in the admin create view).

I feel like I'm missing something obvious, I need to be able to list the SecondaryUser instances in the admin. The `User` class cannot be abstract.

EDIT:
have confirmed they're in the DB:

```
mysql> SELECT * from <app2>_secondaryuser;
+-------------+---------------+-----------+
| user_ptr_id | <field_1>     | <field_2> |
+-------------+---------------+-----------+
|        123  |             0 |         0 |
|        124  |             0 |         0 |
|        125  |             1 |         0 |
+-------------+---------------+-----------+
```

Comment: can you go directly to your database and see if there is objects in the SecondaryUser table ?

Comment: yes they're in the db

Comment: @RHSmith159 Do you have a custom manager on the `SecondaryUser` table?

Comment: Are you sure you mean to inherit from the `User` and not just have an extension model with an OneToOneField?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat The `SecondaryUser` does not have a customer manager, but the `User` does, the manager inherits from django's `BaseUserManager`

Comment: @AKX yes it's got to use inheritance in this case

Comment: @RHSmith159 Why is that? What are you modeling? I've found Django's concrete model inheritance has been troublesome in the past (at least in the absence of e.g. django-polymorphic).